Google Cloud Run - First Deploy - 404
I'm new to Google Cloud and I just deployed a simple app to Cloud Run. The deployment said successful but when I go to the provided URL I get a not found message and the Network tab has a 404. This is an out-of-the-box Cloud Run Service. I haven't touched any of the settings.
When I run the app locally, it works.
Also, when going to my test route with the GCR URL, /api/data, it works. So I think the issue is related to how the client files are being served. But why would it work locally and not in GCR?
These are the steps I took:

created a new Google Cloud Project
built the app with a simple frontend and backend (no database)
ran npm run build from the client folder
deployed with gcloud

Here's a Github repo
Frontend Code: it is an out-of-the-box Preact install in the client folder
Backend Code:
index.js (root)
const server = require('./server');
    
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

index.js (server folder)
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const static = require('koa-static');
const path = require('path');

const server = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

// Serve static files
server.use(static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

// Test route
router.get('/api/data', async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = { message: 'Hello from Koa!' };
});

server.use(router.routes());

module.exports = server;

package.json (root)
{
  "name": "koa-preact-google-run-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.15.3",
    "koa-router": "^12.0.1",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4"
  }
}

package.json (client folder)
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "preact": "^10.20.0",
        "preact-iso": "^2.6.3",
        "preact-render-to-string": "^6.5.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@preact/preset-vite": "^2.8.2",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-config-preact": "^1.4.0",
        "vite": "^5.2.2"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "preact"
    }
}

Logs:



Can you share logs from Google Cloud console?

hi @RoopaM I added screenshots of logs.

In your server, you have server.use(static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));. Add a log/print statement so that you can check the value of the full path and see if it's the right thing/makes sense to you

@NoCommandLine ok I'll try. Does GCR change the file structure upon deployment? Is there a way for me to see the file structure of my app in GCR?

I added these console.logs:
console.log('---PATH DIRNAME', __dirname);
console.log('---PATH TO DIST', (path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
And got these results:
---PATH DIRNAME /workspace/server
---PATH TO DIST /workspace/client/dist

Do something similar for server i.e. path.join(__dirname, '../server/dist') and see if you also get /workspace/server/dist. If you do, then that should eliminate the path to the client (from your code) being the issue

fixed by removing client/dist from .gitignore

I fixed it. On a hunch I removed client/dist from .gitignore and on the next deployment, the frontend started working. I'm not using Github for deployment, so I don't know why that would fix the issue. And it seems odd to me that gcloud would look at .gitignore. I'm using gcloud to deploy from source, with the --source flag, directly from my laptop to GCR, so this fix doesn't make sense to me.
UPDATE: I just found this explanation in the docs.

--source=SOURCE
...  If the source is a local directory, this
command skips the files specified in the --ignore-file. If
--ignore-file is not specified, use .gcloudignore file. If a .gcloudignore file is absent and a .gitignore file is present in the
local source directory, gcloud will use a generated Git-compatible
.gcloudignore file that respects your .gitignored files. The global
.gitignore is not respected.

